Are the bombs sentient/AI?
In the movie The Creator1, the underlying premise is that after Los Angeles was destroyed by a nuclear bomb (which was publically blamed as an AI terrorist attack), that the US outlawed AI and embarked on a global vendetta to rid the planet of AI because AI was deemed as an existential threat to humanity.
Thus almost all the skirmishes the US forces are involved in rely on human based soldiers fighting hand to hand with AI robots/simulants with nary even an exoskeleton to assist them.
However, during one such skirmish the US forces deployed walking/talking G14 bombs that look like an R2D2 that had proper arms and legs instead of the tripod/wheeled legs2.
When one the first of these bombs is deployed:

 It turns to the woman running the attack and says:

 "Command confirmed.  Goodbye ma'am, It's been a pleasure to serve you."

 Before running off to detonate.  Which seems to be very talkative for a bomb from a country that has banned AI.




Are these bombs AI or the type that the US has supposedly banned?  And if so, where did the AI come from?

1. Which I only watched last night because I couldn't sleep.
2. Gareth Edwards also directed Rogue One, so there could be a connection to the body shape there.  And some of the AI robot fighters had an air of Star Wars Battle Droid about them.

Which I only watched last night because I couldn't sleep. ... how is this relevant to the question?
